# Yum Installed Package But I Cant Find It

Tags: centos, yum, command-line-interface, soundtouch

First off please dont instantly down vote as i am not experienced with building and running distributions via the command line its all foreign to me i am learning.

I have a server running on Centos 6 and i am trying to download and install a library called soundtouch.

here: http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-i386/soundtouch-devel-1.5.0-1.el6.i686.rpm.html
and here: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/
I run

```
yum install soundtouch
```

and it runs and seems to install correctly

```
yum install soundtouch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.cogentco.com
 * updates: mirror.rackspace.com
489 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Package soundtouch-1.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 is obsoleted by libsoundtouch-1.7.1-1.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do
```

But when i try to run the command

```
which soundtouch
/usr/bin/which: no soundtouch
```

or

```
soundtouch
-bash: soundtouch: command not found
```

And i check my /usr/bin/ folder and its not there? Can someone please advise where i am going wrong.

Thanks You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not install `soundtouch` package, yum is telling you that this package is obsoleted by `libsoundtouch`. You can check which files belong to that package:

```
rpm -ql libsoundtouch
```